# Get the data out of the emxArray_real_T

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-coder, codegen

I have converted [a simple code to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953739/dealing-with-emxarray-real-t-data-in-c/32956968?noredirect=1#comment53739137_32956968) using Matlab coder. However, my main problem is that I cannot get its output! How can I convert the output which is an emxArray_real_T type to a C++ array and print it?

Answer (score 1):

> **C Code Interface for Dynamically Allocated Arrays**
>
> In generated code, MATLAB represents dynamically allocated data as a
>   structure type called emxArray. An embeddable version of the MATLAB
>   mxArray, the emxArray is a family of data types, specialized for all
>   base types. emxArray Structure Definition
>
> ```
> typedef struct emxArray_<baseTypedef> {
>     <baseType> *data;
>     int *size;
>     int allocatedSize;
>     int numDimensions;
>     boolean_T canFreeData; 
> } emxArray_<baseTypedef>;
> ```
>
> baseTypedef is the predefined type in rtwtypes.h corresponding to
>   baseType. For example, here is the definition for an emxArray of base
>   type double with unknown upper bounds:
>
> ```
> typedef struct emxArray_real_T {
>     double *data;    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< RIGHT HERE
>     int *size;
>     int allocatedSize;
>     int numDimensions;
>     boolean_T canFreeData; 
> } emxArray_real_T;
> ```
>
> The predefined type corresponding to double is real_T. For more
>   information on the correspondence between built-in data types and
>   predefined types in **rtwtypes.h**

http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/c-code-interface-for-unbounded-arrays-and-structure-fields.html?refresh=true

Comment: I know about this, but as I said, my main problem is a practical solution (code) that can give me the output.

Comment: @Sam, does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24271438/3297440) for an example of allocating `emxArray` inputs and outputs help? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32191965/3297440) talks about copying from a `std::vector< std::vector<double> >` to an `emxArray` and you just need to do the reverse. Remember, the data in the `emxArray` will be in column-major order.

Comment: @RyanLivingston: Thanks for those links, I had seen them before and actually could not use them! My function simply is C = A + B, where A and B are two 2D matrices. As I mentioned, I really don't know that how I should extract the output from the matlab generated C++ code!